# struggling with lasagna plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe hcad, which has observations 1:n each with a unique id. In this df, I have observations for different building quality conditions by year: condition_2016, condition_2018, condition_2019, condition_2020, condition_2021, condition _2022. These have ordered values of c("Unsound", "Very Poor", "Poor", "Fair", "Fair/Average", "Average", "Good", "Very Good", "Excellent"). There is also a flood condition flooded_flag.

I want to create two lasagna plots, one where flooded_flag is TRUE and one where it is FALSE. I basically want to sort the 2016 condition on the lefthand side and see how that changes by year for each id to look kinda like this:

[image]

This is where I've gotten and I am very stuck:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(viridis)

set.seed(123)  # For reproducibility
n <- 1000
prob_false <- 0.7 

# Define ordered levels for the condition variable
condition_levels <- c("Unsound", "Very Poor", "Poor", "Fair", "Fair/Average", "Average", "Good", "Very Good", "Excellent")

# Create a data frame with sampled values for flooded_flag and condition for each year
hcad <- data.frame(
  id = paste0("id", 1:n),
  flooded_flag = sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1 - prob_false, prob_false)),
  condition_2016 = factor(sample(condition_levels, n, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE, levels = condition_levels),
  condition_2018 = factor(sample(condition_levels, n, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE, levels = condition_levels),
  condition_2019 = factor(sample(condition_levels, n, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE, levels = condition_levels),
  condition_2020 = factor(sample(condition_levels, n, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE, levels = condition_levels),
  condition_2021 = factor(sample(condition_levels, n, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE, levels = condition_levels),
  condition_2022 = factor(sample(condition_levels, n, replace = TRUE), ordered = TRUE, levels = condition_levels)
)


hcad_long <- pivot_longer(hcad, starts_with("condition_"), names_to = "year", values_to = "condition")
hcad_long$year <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", hcad_long$year))


lasagna_plot <- ggplot(hcad_long, aes(
  x = as.numeric(year),
  y = id,
  fill = as.factor(condition)
)) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = as.numeric(year) - 0.5,
      xmax = as.numeric(year) + 0.5,
      ymin = as.numeric(id) - 0.45,
      ymax = as.numeric(id) + 0.45
    )
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Lasagna Plot of Condition Changes by Year",
    x = "Year",
    y = "ID"
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(as.numeric(hcad_long$year)), labels = unique(hcad_long$year)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = unique(hcad_long$id)) +
  facet_wrap(~flooded_flag) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  )

lasagna_plot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `id` is a character. hence, when converting to a numeric you get NA. Instead, convert to a `factor` first. Additionally I switched to a continuous y scale as 1000 breaks are far too much to display on a discrete scale.

```
library(ggplot2)

lasagna_plot <- ggplot(hcad_long, aes(
  x = as.numeric(year),
  y = as.numeric(gsub("^id", "", id)),
  fill = as.factor(condition)
)) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = as.numeric(year) - 0.5,
      xmax = as.numeric(year) + 0.5,
      ymin = as.numeric(factor(id)) - 0.45,
      ymax = as.numeric(factor(id)) + 0.45
    )
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Lasagna Plot of Condition Changes by Year",
    x = "Year",
    y = "ID"
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(as.numeric(hcad_long$year)), labels = unique(hcad_long$year)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, NA)) +
  facet_wrap(~flooded_flag) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  )

lasagna_plot
```

[image]

Moreover, to get a plot more in line with the chart in the referenced image I would suggest to rearrange or recode your `id`s by `floodedflag` and conditions before reshaping to long and setting `scale="free_y"`in `facet_wrap`.

```
hcad <- hcad |>
  arrange(
    flooded_flag, across(starts_with("condition"))
  ) |>
  mutate(
    id = paste0("id", row_number()),
    id = forcats::fct_inorder(id)
  )

hcad_long <- pivot_longer(hcad, starts_with("condition_"),
  names_to = "year", values_to = "condition"
)
hcad_long$year <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", hcad_long$year))

library(ggplot2)

lasagna_plot <- ggplot(hcad_long, aes(
  x = as.numeric(year),
  y = as.numeric(gsub("^id", "", id)),
  fill = as.factor(condition)
)) +
  geom_rect(
    aes(
      xmin = as.numeric(year) - 0.5,
      xmax = as.numeric(year) + 0.5,
      ymin = as.numeric(factor(id)) - 0.45,
      ymax = as.numeric(factor(id)) + 0.45
    )
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Lasagna Plot of Condition Changes by Year",
    x = "Year",
    y = "ID"
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = unique(hcad_long$year)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~flooded_flag, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  )

lasagna_plot
```

[image]

**EDIT** To get rid of the white stripes map `condition` on `color` too and switch to `geom_tile`.

```
library(ggplot2)

lasagna_plot <- ggplot(hcad_long, aes(
  x = as.numeric(year),
  y = as.numeric(gsub("^id", "", id)),
  fill = factor(condition),
  color = factor(condition)
)) +
  geom_tile() +
  labs(
    title = "Lasagna Plot of Condition Changes by Year",
    x = "Year",
    y = "ID"
  ) +
  scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = unique(hcad_long$year)
  ) +
  facet_wrap(~flooded_flag, scales = "free_y") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)
  )

lasagna_plot
```

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! Follow up question: why do the colors have white lines through them? Like on the lefthand side, the yellow, fair and poor are solid blocks, but the very good and good etc have tons of lines through them?

Comment: One reason ist that you have set height of the rects to `.9 = 2 * .45`. However, even when using `.5` it will not work perfectly. But after a second look we can fix that by switching to geom_tile which also simplifies the code. See my edit.